# TypeError when calling a method of a class

Tags: python, class

```
class Product(object):

 def __init__(self, ind, name, price, quantity):

    self.ind = ind
    self.name = name
    self.price = price
    self.quantity = quantity


 inventory = list()


 def add(self):


    inventory.append(Product(self.ind))
    inventory.append(Product(self.name))
    inventory.append(Product(self.price))
    inventory.append(Product(self.quantity))
    print('product %s added')%name

Product.add(63456, 'Meow', 60.00, 0)
```

I am still getting an error:

```
  Product.add(63456, 'Meow', 60.00, 0)
TypeError: unbound method add() must be called with Product instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

and I have no idea what is wrong with this since I just started learning about classes.

What needs to be changed?

Comment: Your code contains numerous errors.  I think it would be best if you backed up and read a [basic Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) before continuing.  Once you understand the fundamentals of Python, you can move on to more advanced subjects such as classes and OOP.

Comment: What errors dou you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method call is wrong. You should call it with object reference. And one more thing you have to define your list as **global** then only you will be able to append next element. Otherwise it will give **NameError: global name 'inventory' is not defined** error. 
Try this out:

```
class Product(object):

    def __init__(self, ind, name, price, quantity):
        self.ind = ind
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity        

    global inventory
    inventory = []

    def add(self):
        inventory.append(self.ind)
        inventory.append(self.name)
        inventory.append(self.price)
        inventory.append(self.quantity)
        print('product %s added')% self.name

obj = Product(63456, 'Meow', 60.00, 0)
obj.add()
```

Or If you want to have the separate copy of inventory for each object then define inventory as `self.inventory = []`
Hence your code will look something like:

```
class Product(object):

    def __init__(self, ind, name, price, quantity):
        self.ind = ind
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity        
        self.inventory = []


    def add(self):
        self.inventory.append(self.ind)
        self.inventory.append(self.name)
        self.inventory.append(self.price)
        self.inventory.append(self.quantity)
        print('product %s added')% self.name

obj = Product(63456, 'Meow', 60.00, 0)
obj.add()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the method as if it were a static method. It is an instance method. You need to create an instance of `Product`, then call the method on that instance.

```
my_product = Product(63456, 'Meow', 60.00, 0)
my_product.add()
```